# Can environment markers be used for determining the Databricks Runtime

Tags: python, databricks

We are creating a generic library in Python used by different (LTS) [runtimes on Databricks](https://docs.databricks.com/release-notes/runtime/releases.html) that is used in highly automated release pipelines. So we have not exact control over the libraries and dependencies that are already installed and which ones needs to be installed. Therefore I'd like a requirements file that can install packages conditionally. Normally that would be done by environment markers described in [PEP 0508](https://peps.python.org/pep-0508/).

Unfortunately none of these markers can directly tell me which Databricks Runtime we are running on. Are there environment markers that can be used to derive the Databricks Runtime or are there other ways to retrieve the DB Runtime and install packages based on this runtime?

Comment: I am not sure if the information is available somewhere but provided you know the cluster-id, you can find similar information mentioned using the [cluster API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/clusters.html#get) or the databricks-cli command `databricks clusters get --cluster-id <cluster_id> | grep spark_version` which would give couple of lines - `"spark_version": "10.4.x-scala2.12",
  "effective_spark_version": "10.4.x-scala2.12",` where 10.4.x- is the runtime right ? see if this works for you - maybe someone will direct you to an official way of getting this info.

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of spark configuration options with name having prefix `spark.databricks.clusterUsageTags`.  To get DBR version you need the `spark.databricks.clusterUsageTags.sparkVersion` configuration - just do:

```py
spark.conf.get("spark.databricks.clusterUsageTags.sparkVersion")
```